# Using Max() on SUM() Aggregate function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sum, max

I am trying to write a query in Oracle which will return both the pub_id and the maximum total revenue from a titles table which lists pub_id, sales, price. 
I can get either a listing with pub_id and total revenues for each pub_id with

```
 SELECT PUB_ID, SUM(SALES*PRICE) as TotalRevenue FROM TITLES GROUP BY PUB_ID;
```

Or I can get just the MAX(Sales*Price) with

```
 SELECT MAX(SUM(sales*price)) FROM titles GROUP BY pub_id;
```

Any ideas how can I get the pub_id out with the maximum of the total revenue?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the rank function like this

```
select * from
(
select a.*,rank() over (order by sum_sales desc) r from
(
select pub_id,sum(sales*price) sum_sales from titles group by pub_id
) a
)
where r = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks @Greg. It gives me just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

That's simple with the powerful **`ORACLE ANALYTICAL FUNCTIONS`**

Below will give the max revenues for each `pub_id`.

```
  select pub_id,REV from 
   (
   select pub_id, (sales*price) as REV,
   max(sales*price) over (partition by pub_id order by 1) as MAX 
   from titles
   )
   where REV=MAX
```

If you want to determine the `pub_id` with the maximum revenue:

```
   select * from
   (
   select pub_id,REV from 
   (
   select pub_id, (sales*price) as REV,
   max(sales*price) over (partition by pub_id order by 1) as MAX 
   from titles
   )
   where REV=MAX order by MAX desc
   )
   where rownum<2
```

Comment: Thanks @bonsvr However keep getting this error "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected"

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT PUB_ID, SUM(SALES*PRICE) as TotalRevenue 
FROM TITLES 
GROUP BY PUB_ID
HAVING SUM(SALES*PRICE) = ( SELECT MAX(SUM(SALES*PRICE)) 
                            FROM TITLES 
                            GROUP BY PUB_ID );
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no really need for analytic functions in this case. The best option would be to group two times one for the sum() and the following time for the max() with the [dense_rank](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions083.htm#i1000905) option.

```
select max(pub_id) keep (dense_rank last order by TotalRevenue)
from (
        SELECT PUB_ID, SUM(SALES*PRICE) as TotalRevenue 
        FROM TITLES 
        GROUP BY PUB_ID
    )
```

Comment: Thanks @Alessandro. Not familiar with dense_rank yet but will be soon.